# Yocto issue with meta-java

Tags: java, linux, yocto, bitbake

I am using Yocto Poky-Thud. I cloned the latest branch of the meta-java layer from *https://git.yoctoproject.org/git/meta-java*

However, on attempt to build a simple recipe, after one hour or so, I get the following errors below relating to icedtea7 which is not easy to understand. Would anybody have an idea what is the issue?

```
ERROR: icedtea7-native-2.1.3-r1.0 do_configure: configure failed
ERROR: icedtea7-native-2.1.3-r1.0 do_configure: Function failed: 
do_configure (log file is located at 
/home/ubuntu/JUMPNOW/bbb/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/icedtea7-native/2.1.3- 
r1.0/temp/log.do_configure.14801)
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: 
/home/ubuntu/JUMPNOW/bbb/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/icedtea7-native/2.1.3- 
r1.0/temp/log.do_configure.14801
```

Then further down in the messages :

```
ERROR: Task (/home/ubuntu/JUMPNOW/poky-thud/meta-java/recipes- 
core/icedtea/icedtea7-native_2.1.3.bb:do_configure) failed with exit code 
'1'
```

Comment: Did you check the log file?

Comment: @ErkiA , Yes             "NOTE: /home/ubuntu/JUMPNOW/bbb/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/icedtea7-native/2.1.3-r1.0/icedtea-2.1.3/build/config.log
ERROR: configure failed
WARNING: /home/ubuntu/JUMPNOW/bbb/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/icedtea7-native/2.1.3-r1.0/temp/run.do_configure.14801:1 exit 1 from 'exit 1'
ERROR: Function failed: do_configure (log file is located at /home/ubuntu/JUMPNOW/bbb/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/icedtea7-native/2.1.3-r1.0/temp/log.do_configure.1480$"

Comment: Did you look at [Known Limitations/Bugs](https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/meta-java/tree/README?h=thud)? You can try to set another `PREFERRED_PROVIDER` for native recipes (in same README file).